# Blocking SSH Connection Using Scheduled Task

Tags: networking, ssh, internet, python

I have a Python script to block SSH connection. When I keep running the program in CMD console, it successfully blocks port 22.

But when I set the script as a scheduled task (run as administrator in Windows PC) then the program can not block SSH.

What can be the root cause?

Comment: why do you not use a firewall?

Comment: Actually I am using windivert service to create my own network listener. When I run the program manually, it works fine. But when running my program using scheduled task, it can't block. Worth to note, I also block port 80 which has no issues but only port 22 has issues.

Comment: The scheduler's environment is different. It doesn't for example have the PATH variable. Without knowing what your program does, we can't really answer.